# Why SQL Server doesn't allow to remove a Distributor exactly after Configuration?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, distribution, database-replication

I Configured a distribution in SQL Server 2008 using both Wizard and T-SQL but after it when I want to remove it Using Wizard (right clicking on Replication and choosing 'Disable Publishing and Distribution...') or executing following command with and without its parameters:

```
exec sp_dropdistributor @no_checks = 1 -- no new results with @ignore_distributor = 1
```

this Error would be presented:

> Msq 21122, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dropdistributiondb Line 124
>   Cannot drop the distribution database 'lobloblob' because it is
>   currently in use.

I didn't publish any thing, didn't configure any subscription but gave this error
what should I do ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

> SELECT spid FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE dbid = db_id('distribution')

Kill the spid and try again.  Now it should work.

Answer (score 7):

I used the following scripts:

```
SELECT spid FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE dbid = db_id('distribution')
```

and found that the session_id of current session (which contains the distribution configuration script) doesn't allow to disable distribution so i suggest this script to kill running spid to drop distribution:

```
use [master]
declare @spid varchar(10)
select @spid=spid from sys.sysprocesses where dbid = DB_ID('distribution')

while @@ROWCOUNTS <> 0
    exec ('KILL ' + @spid)

exec sp_dropdistributor @no_checks = 1
```

Comment: This woorked for me SQLServer 2008 R2. However is `@@ROWCOUNT` not `@@ROWCOUNTS`

Comment: I don't understand why that wile loop is necessary. I don't think that loop is necessary, or that the code is just wrong (perhaps you meant to select the @spid=spid inside the loop?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the distribution cleanup job is causing the problem.  But, to check, prepare to execute the sp_dropdistributor in one window in SSMS and note the session_id of the window.  In a second, prepare to run `select session_id from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks where blocked_session_id = <spid from window 1>`.  Back in window 1, run the proc and then switch back to window 2 and run the select.  it'll tell you the session_ids of the sessions blocking the drop of the database.